# Implementing Subsets of Foreign Keys in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, foreign-keys

I'm building a forum-style website in Django, and have been running into some issues in my design structure. The relevant code (from my model) looks like:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    post_count = models.IntegerField()

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
```

The issue that I am having is that in my view and template, I iterate through threads and display posts. However, I have a desire to communicate to my template that a post might have certain "special properties" (e.g., thread originator, latest post(s), highest-scoring post(s), etc.). It seems reasonable to me that these would be properties of the thread and not the post itself (as each thread would have these, but only a variable/negligible number of posts would) but the solutions to this problem that I've managed to compose have involved doubly-linking the posts to the thread (via another ForeignKey(Thread) in the Post definition) or by placing BooleanFields in the Post definition to indicate status in these lists. I'm not even sure these would work or be visible in the Django template.

My question: is there a clean way in Django to specialize or group instances of a model that are already linked by being sister elements in a foreign key, i.e., to subset a ForeignKey into seperate (and possibly overlapping) groups? Or am I approaching this problem in a nonpythonic/nondjango way? Any insight or links to documentation I may have overlooked would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add certain properties as ManyToManyField in Thread

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    post_count = models.IntegerField()
    post_latest = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='as_latest', null=True, blank=True)
```

Or, I prefer use @property to get the data you need with certain properties:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    post_count = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def post_latest(self):
        return self.post_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
```